# Access Denied when attempting to create an alert in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I honestly don't know whether this question belongs on SO or SF, but thought I'd start here.

When attempting to create a new alert in a team project in TFS 2015 (Update 1) via the Web interface where the subscriber is a project team, I get this message:

> Failed to save one or more alerts:
>   Access Denied: [MyProject]\MyProject Team needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: View collection-level information

Of course, a project team doesn't have collection-level permissions available to it (AFAIK). I tried explicitly allowing View collection-level information for all of the team's members, but still no luck. I am the Team Foundation Administrator, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue on my end.

Here are the details of the alert I was trying to create:

```
Name: A work item is assigned to me
Subscriber: MyProject Team
Send to: [Members' default alert address]
Format: HTML
Alert filters:
    And/or   Field           Operator     Value
             Team Project    =            MyProject
    And      Assigned To     Changes to   [Me]
    And      Authorized As   <>           [Me]
```

Upon clicking the OK button, I receive the message above. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

### Update:

I don't find any permissions at the collection level for the team:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the permission for "[MyProject]\MyProject Team" group?

Comment: Unless I'm way off base, project teams can't be assigned collection-level permissions. At least, there's no "View collection-level information" permission listed for MyProject Team.

Comment: Cannot add image in comments, please refer to the image in my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've been unable to find any better answer than giving all of the individual users that make up the AD groups explicit Allow permission for "View collection-level information." The *implicit* Allow that all contributors have by default was not sufficient, nor was giving the AD *groups* explicit Allow. I can't find a rational explanation for this, so I don't discount the possibility that I'm simply overlooking something obvious, but I didn't want this question to sit out here forever without an answer. Perhaps this information will be of use to someone else at some point. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First you can double check if anyone with sufficient rights (Team Project Administrator, Team Project Collection Administrator, or TFS Admin) has changed the security at the Team Project or Team Project Collection level such that a "Deny" has been set? In TFS, **deny will trump allow**. Even though your security seems to be correct from what you describe.

If the permission sets without problem, this may caused by **a delay in TFS** picking up changes to the domain security groups. You can check the detail blogs to [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)  or [Identity Synchronization in Team Foundation Server 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vasu_sankaran/archive/2010/06/07/identity-synchronization-in-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I've checked every group, user, and team, and none of them have that permission set to Deny. The security settings have been in place for a couple of weeks now, so I doubt it is a synchronization issue, but just to be sure, I tried the suggestions in both of the blog posts you linked (there doesn't appear to be a TFS 2015 version of TfsSyncIdentities, so I used the 2013 version), and I get the same error. If you have any other thoughts, please let me know.

Comment: Out of desperation, I tried giving explicit Allow for that setting to each of the _individual users_ in each of the AD groups that make up that team. After doing that, it worked. I am not entirely sure if this is a coincidence -- maybe some kind of synchronization finally "went through?" It doesn't seem, though, that this should be necessary. It's going to become a maintenance headache for certain. @Patrick, what are your thoughts?

Comment: No, good suggestion. Generally speaking, don't need to explicit allow permission for each user in the team. Suggest you to delete the team group and readd it again in TFS. And give the team the permission directly. This may do the trick. You can test it in another team.

Comment: I don't think you can assign collection-level permissions to project teams, can you? At least, there doesn't appear to be a way to do that through the UI.

Comment: A Project Team is a security group with special powers. You can give View Collection level  information to a group.

Comment: I am  pretty sure that View Collection Level Info is default for all contributors

Comment: @MrHinsh, yes, by default all contributors have implicit allow for this permission. For whatever reason, it seems that they require explicit allow, though. I know, it doesn't make sense to me either. I'm just reporting what I've experienced. I would be glad if it could be demonstrated that I'm just being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can check or set the permission for a group via following steps:

1. Open the "Control Panel" settings for you collection. (Not for project)
2. Open "Security" tab.
3. Enter "[MyProject]\MyProject Team" in the textbox to search that group.
   Then you can set the permission for that group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't find any permissions at the collection level for the team. I only find permissions at the project level. The team was created automatically when the team project was created. See screenshot in my update to the original question.